# How to create apps for mobiles which are using KaiOS?

Tags: operating-system, mobile-application, firefox-os, 4g, kaios

I recently found in news that [**KaiOS**](http://www.kaiostech.com/) has been used in 4G Volte Enabled feature mobile phones. I was wondering how to create apps for KaiOS. Any help on creating apps for KaiOS has been greatly appreciated.

Comment: KaiOS is the 'bare' linux-based OS. The Volt has it's own 'UI', 'Feature Phone Features' and framework, drivers, etc on top. Can write a simple 'hello world', no problem (all x86 target?) - need to hookup IO of course.

Comment: Checkout this https://developer.kaiostech.com/

Comment: You can't, the store is top down curated and they don't accept apps from non established company entities as far as i can understand(they never responded to my email about my ready  to go app)

Answer (score 8):

You can find the kickstart here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/Firefox_OS_apps/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS but as KaiOS is B2G forked i would still suggest you to go to kaiOS official website to check the proper flow for the application development.

Below are the series of steps you need to go through if you don't want to get stuck in between of development:

- First you should understand how applications actually work in kaiOS environment and for that you need to first understand the architecture for that. You can give a read to  https://developer.kaiostech.com/introduction/architecture for more understanding.
- Then comes setup for your application which you will find here at https://developer.kaiostech.com/environment-setup . Mozzila firefox shift+F8 will open the webIDE where you can see your devices connected but for that you should have proper drivers installed for your phone. You can use firefox emulator 2.2 (stable) as well for initial start.
- Now its time to have your first application onboard to kaiOS . You can make your application in any of the client specific JS like angular , react or even plain javascript but the important part is to have manifest.webapp in root folder for compatibility.You can give a read to https://developer.kaiostech.com/first-app.
- You are able to see your first application on your phone !! Now the real pain arrives when it comes to navigate through the application by keypad but thanks to naviboard library which will do this work for you to align your navigable items and navigate through it by simple API’s. You can find the library at https://github.com/amanboss9/naviboard.
- When you are done with navigation part of feature phone, you can go through and develop as much as you can as if it is a web application and can develop a lot of things.
- Check the sample project at  [https://github.com/amanboss9/kaios-angular-app](https://github.com/amanboss9/naviboard). This Boilerplate can save lot of time when it comes to setting up everything from scratch.It included Angular1.6, naviboardJS(For auto handling navigation part of your application) and Gulp.

Answer (score 3):

KaiOS is based on Mozilla's open source B2G OS. The apps are built purely with HTML/JS/CSS stack and any web application/website that is mobile friendly can be an app with just minor modifications. You can use the inbuilt webIDE to build apps for Mozilla OS, see more here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/Firefox_OS_apps/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/Firefox_OS_app_beginners_tutorial

I used to build apps for Firefox OS before it was dead lets hope to see whether it's reincarnation succeeds.

I will try making apps when I get my hands on the Jio Phone and will update here.

**Update:**

KaiOS has released a newly updated their website with a new IDE called Kaiosrt which is much better and actually works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes saw that yesterday, so I guess it is just going to be a fancy fork of Mozilla's B2G OS. So web IDE should work fine in running apps on the JIO Phone.

Comment: I don't seem to find the simulator for Jio phones in the webIDE...where did you get that??

Comment: Currently WebIDE is not providing simulator for Jio Phones. If you look closely above code template, it used image of JIO phone.

Comment: @dsaket We are just speculating that this is how we build apps for the JIO phone since KaiOS is a fork of Firefox OS just made for feature phones.

Comment: @SachinPachkude See this for how Kai OS will look https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=alcatel+go+flip

Comment: ok cool...actually I need a simulator for non-touch-screen devices to build a web app on KaiOS and I have no idea how to get started.

Comment: @dsaket I guess you have to wait until JIO phones roll out, I even raised a query on KaiOS on building apps and still waiting for a response.

Comment: Yes @satheeshwaran.. it uses KaiOS Simple-to-use Interface.

Comment: @satheeshwaran Did you find any way to develop/test an app in JIO phone?

Comment: So far no luck, I tried to connect JIO phone to the Mozilla debugger but it did not recognize.

Comment: Sent a query to the kaios team and this is their response,Hi there,

I’m sorry you haven’t heard back from us on this. We’ve been extremely busy with the launch and delivery of the JioPhone. 

For these type of inquiries we’re still coordinating between Jio and ourselves how these should be handled and by whom. 

I expect to give you a clearer answer on this in the coming weeks.

Thanks for your patience and let me know if you have any other questions in the meantime. 

Kind regards,
Tim Metz

Sent from mobile

Comment: Does anyone know how to view the OS files? I tried hooking up via USB but that obviously shows only the media and some files encoded in some format I can't understand (not base64 apparently).

Comment: Another phone with KaiOS - "Nokia 8110 4G". Checkout this link https://www.indiatoday.in/technology/features/story/nokia-8110-4g-quick-review-the-banana-phone-strikes-back-1178371-2018-02-27

Comment: @SachinPachkude have you been able to find a simulator?

Comment: @sv94: For KaiOS I am yet to find any simulator.

Comment: Any success on how to install the app on jio phone ? Need a small app using nfc feature if any one can help. I am looking for paid help. Please contact ersaurabh101@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

**KaiOS is a B2G OS forked from Firefox OS.**

- You can use Angular/React/Jquery or any JS lib/framework to develop apps on Kaios
- Packaged app should have all js/image/html/css file packed locally, External link reference in index.html will not work. Blocked by default- CSP policy.
- Mobiles (JioPhone/Nokia Banana phone) with keyboard needs to handle its own key events, Refer [Kaios Sample app](https://github.com/svarunan/firefox-os-sample-app)

Answer (score 1):

This is in the FAQs of KaiOS offical website:

> **Can I develop apps for KaiOS?**
>
> KaiOS is a curated platform for apps and we are working closely with
>   app developers to provide the best experience for our users. At the
>   moment we are not accepting submissions into the Store, but will do so
>   in the future.

(https://www.kaiostech.com/faq/#question-12)

Guess you could leave your contact email there and will get updates in the near future.

Comment: Already send a query to them about app development for KaiOS but apart from auto generated response mail, still waiting for answers.

Answer (score 1):

**KaiOS** have officially launched the KaiOS [**Developer Portal**](https://developer.kaiostech.com/).
It's got everything developers need to start building and distributing KaiOS apps.

> Furthermore, build your first app with **JavaScript (Vanilla), React,
>   Vue.js and Angular** with code examples [**herein**](https://developer.kaiostech.com/getting-started/build-your-first-package-app/sample-code). Then, testing your
>   apps with **[WebIDE or Simulator](https://developer.kaiostech.com/getting-started/build-your-first-package-app/test-your-apps)**.

---

Tools and resources include:

- [**A guide to building your first app**](https://developer.kaiostech.com/getting-started), with sample code, reference guides, and software development kits (SDKs).
- **[Instructions for ENV setup](https://developer.kaiostech.com/getting-started/env-setup)** to configure your development environment.
- **[A simulator](https://developer.kaiostech.com/getting-started/env-setup/simulator)** running Gaia and web apps in a Gecko-based environment.